# HTML file upload page using webview in iPhone environment

Tags: iphone, html, file-upload, uiwebview

I am working in iPhone 4.3 environment. My requirement is that I design the html page with a file upload feature, and I need to include this html file into the webview. By selecting the upload button, I need to browse my device photos and videos, so that I can upload into the server.

Is that possible? It would be really helpful if I could get any working samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do what you looking for.

In your html code , your upload button should call javascript that will call your browsing photos and video objective-c code

The technique is calling objective-c code from javascript , see also : [WebKit DOM Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215) here.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, it will be very helpful, if any samples available to proceed further.

Comment: The link above is enough more or try to custom with your code look up there http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/calling-objective-c-from-javascript-in-an-iphone-uiwebview/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.But you can not use the webkit DOM because it's not available for iOS.

My solution is:

1. click html button, call javascript to change the value of window.location.hash e.g. window.location.hash="uploadImg;uploadUrl";
2. using -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType to monitor the change of hash code attached to current url; if "uploadImg;uploadUrl" is found in the current url, invoke the native objective-c code to browse photo or take new picture and upload the picture to url specified by uploadUrl;

   when upload is done, native code could call javascript by

   NSString *markupResult = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"callback_javascript_upload()"];